# Panel doesn't show on selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have three panels. 
Panel 1: Checking/Savings
Panel 2: Credit Card
Panel 3: Cancel

On page load I am retrieving the payment information and I select the checkbox corresponding to their previous payment selection. The checkbox gets selected but the panel doesn't show. Also, if I could hide the btnsubmit on page load that would be great because once I click the option the panel shows.

Thank you!

```
  function panelOneFocus() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= chkOption1.ClientID %>").checked) {
            jQuery('#divOption2').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption3').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption1').css("display", "inline");
            jQuery('#<%= chkOption2.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=chkOption3.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').removeClass("disabled");
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
    function panelTwoFocus() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= chkOption2.ClientID %>").checked) {
            jQuery('#divOption1').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption3').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption2').css("display", "inline");
            jQuery('#divFinal').css("display", "inline");
            jQuery('#<%=chkOption1.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=chkOption3.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').removeClass("disabled");
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').removeAttr("disabled");
          }

    }
    function panelThreeFocus() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%= chkOption3.ClientID %>").checked) {
            jQuery('#divOption1').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption2').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#divOption3').css("display", "inline");
            jQuery('#divFinal').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#<%=chkOption1.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=chkOption2.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').addClass("disabled");
            jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        }
    }
```

Comment: How are any of the above functions called? On a button click or other event handler?

Comment: Lotta missed opportunities for shorthand. Can use `$()` instead of `jQuery()` (unless there's conflicts), could just do `.hide()` instead of `.css("display", "none")`. Instead of `document.getElementById()`, simply `$("#"+...)`. I'm not sure, but I think you mean to do `.prop("checked")` instead of `.checked` (`.checked` isn't a thing). Not an answer, but I just wanted to address those things, if you want to get the most out of jQuery.

Comment: Also, what is `<%= chkOption1.ClientID %>`? Is that server-side code, I'm assuming? That won't actually work on the client-side.

Comment: @Philtune I used jQuery('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>').hide(); for page load and recall the button as show under panelOneFocus and panelTwoFocus and is working! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Lily So are these methods called or not? How do you debug your code?

Comment: @philtune: `<%= chkOption1.ClientID %>` is an ASP.Net Inline Expression which (in this case) will render an `id` for client-side use. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112.

Comment: @Wolff: One a button click from a different page I redirect to the page that contains this panels. On the page load I call two methods: GetData() and LoadStates(). The GetData() method retrieves the information that the user used before as payment and the checkbox for the option is selected. Ex:  case 2:{ chkOption2.Checked = true; ...  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "scriptKey", "panelTwoFocus();", true); break;}. The problem was and still is that PanelTwo will not show despite the fact that checkbox 2 was selected. If I unclick and click then it will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting my comment in Answer form:

<strike>I'm not sure, but I think you mean to do `.prop("checked")` instead of `.checked` (`.checked` isn't a thing).</strike> I stand corrected (thanks A. Wolff)

Lotta missed opportunities for shorthand. Can use `$()` instead of `jQuery()` (unless there's conflicts), could just do `.hide()` instead of `.css("display", "none")`. Instead of `document.getElementById()`, simply `$("#"+...)`. These are not part of the answer, but I just wanted to address those things, if you want to get the most out of jQuery.

Comment: `.checked` is a property of input checkbox, it works the same as `.prop("checked")`

Comment: @A.Wolff not disagreeing, but could you provide documentation of that? I couldn't find that anywhere.